# How can I pass a filename with space so it can get the filename via sftp in expect

Tags: shell, expect

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/ksh
RemoteFile=`grep "${File}" ${TempLog}` --> the value of the variable is Site Information_2013-07-04-00-01-26.CSV

/usr/bin/expect << EOF
spawn sftp user@server
expect "password:"
send "123fakepassword\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /home/user/pickup_dir\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "lcd /home/user/Scripts/mart/wmt/RAMDISK0\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "get $RemoteFile\n" ---> I'm  trying to pass it here so I can download the file. 
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\r"
EOF
```

But no luck!, How can I pass a filename with double quote so the it will execute as (get "Site Information_2013-07-04-00-01-26.CSV\n") I'm placing it in variable cause the filename change on date. Or A'm I doing it wrong? I know not good to hard code the password but we can't use ssh-key to have a passwordless sftp. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to send some quotes. Pick one of

```
send "get '$RemoteFile'\n"
send "get \"$RemoteFile\"\n"
```

Comment: I glenn thanks for the reply I did  with single quote I get below error:
sftp> get 'Site Information_2013-07-04-00-01-26.CSV
'
Unterminated quoted argument

for the double quote:
sftp> extra characters after close-quote
    while executing
"\n"d "get "Site Information_2013-07-04-00-01-26.CSV
"
I tried also putting it in expect variable set file \"$RemoteFile\" or set file $RemoteFile and call it, still could not download the file

Comment: I did a workaround used sed:

File=$(echo "$RemoteFile" | sed 's/^/\\"/;s/$/\\"/' | sed 's/^M//')

then call it in my except script

send "get $File\n"

Comment: The better solution would be to remove carriable returns from $TempLog -- `dos2unix "$TempLog"` or `sed -i 's/\r$//' "$TempLog"` -- do this *before* you assign the RemoteFile variable.

Comment: i don't have dos2unix installed but the sed works fine. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do

/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
set timeout 300
spawn sftp $remoteUser@$remoteIp
expect "yes/no" { 
    send "yes\r"
    expect "*?assword" { send "$remotePass\r" }
    } "*?assword" { send "$remotePass\r" }
expect "sftp> " { send "cd $RemoteFolderPath\r" }
expect "sftp> " { send "mget $remoteFileName\r" }
expect "sftp> " { send "quit\r" }
interact
EOF

done

exit
```