# How to put double quotes with in the value with space of a variable in kornshell

Tags: shell, ksh

Below is my code snipt, I'm trying to output a filename to have double quotes on both end.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
.......
##the value is: Site Information_2013-07-05-00-01-26.CSV
RemoteFile=$(grep "$File" "$TempLog")


 ##then Im trying to redirect it to a file so that it will have double quotes 
 echo "\"$RemoteFile\"" > cmd

 ##I'm expecting below output.
"Site Information_2013-07-05-00-01-26.CSV"

##instead, the double quote is missing at the end, can someone point out what I'm doing wrong 

"Site Information_2013-07-05-00-01-26.CSV
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code is fine, so there's a problem in something you're not showing us.

Comment: Even `echo \"$RemoteFile\"` should suffice.

Comment: Just for the sake of experiment - what would `echo "\"$RemoteFile\"\"" > cmd` return?

Comment: here is the out put using echo "\"$RemoteFile\"\""

    ""ite Information_2013-07-05-00-01-26.CSV

Comment: I think I know why its not working its throwing carriage return ^M, problem I don't have dos2unix and I'm not sure why is this happening Im using a aix box

Comment: I have a workaround

echo "$RemoteFile" | sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/' | sed 's/^M//' > cmdFile

I'm now getting "Site Information_2013-07-05-00-01-26.CSV"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a filename with space so it can get the filename via sftp in expect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468638/how-can-i-pass-a-filename-with-space-so-it-can-get-the-filename-via-sftp-in-expe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TempLog contains lines ending with carriage return. 2 solutions

```
dos2unix "$TempLog"
sed -i 's/\r$//' "$TempLog"
```

The double quote is missing at the end because after the "V" there is a carriage return that moves the "cursor" back to the beginning of the line. Then the quote is printed, overwriting the first character (which also happens to be a quote).

Comment: thank, actually I posted 2 because I was looking each solution on passing a space on expect or I'll just do it via variable. Any this is resolved. thanks